# Is there a way to save a not yet finished answer such that I can shut down my PC and contimue working on it later?

Tags: support

Is there a way to save a draft of a not yet finished answer I am writing, such that I can shut down my computer and continue working on it later?

My not obtimal sulotion for far for this problem is to "hide" the unfinished answer for users with <10000 rep, work on it as long as it takes me, and redisplay it for the full audience when I have finished it. But the bumping of the question with each edit even of hidden answers is some kind of annoying.

So is there a better solution supported by Stack Exchange?

Comment: How about using a notepad if you have a long answer and you don't believe in *drafts*?

Comment: FWIW I don't 100% trust the site to store my partially completed answers. I haven't lost data yet, but given that sometimes it refuses to let me discard a draft, I figure the system is not foolproof. I trust my text editor more.

Comment: @ChrisWhite Yep, I do the same. Well, I use Google Docs or `gedit`, but same difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drafts are automatically saved every few minutes; if you visit the page again the text will be available to you. IIRC you can only have one question draft and one answer draft at a time, though.

Comment: Thanks, I have seen that a draft is continuously safed when writing a post, but how exactly do I retrieve the draft, after doing something else on Physics SE or been logged off?

Comment: @Dilaton Just visit the same page.

Comment: I just started to type a test question on the main page, but when leaving by clicking on "questions", a message tells me that the data I just typed are at a risk of getting lost. The same happens for answers. Should I then just ignore that message?

Comment: @Dilaton yep. Note that the draft saving is periodic and some of the typed data ma get lost

Comment: @Manishearth: It is my experience that auto-save is not a reliable in practice.

Comment: @Qmechanic I know, I rarely rely on it. Still, it's there.